# Is it possible to force non-const virtual methods from superclasses to take precedence over const methods of the same name in a subclass?

Tags: c++, oop, constants

Consider the following class definitions:

```
class foo {
  virtual absl::Span<const Input *const> GetInputs() const = 0;

  virtual absl::Span<Input *const> GetInputs() {
    auto mutable_inputs = GetMutableInputs();
    return absl::MakeSpan(mutable_inputs.begin(), mutable_inputs.end());
  }
}

class bar : public foo {
  absl::Span<const Input *const> GetInputs() const override {
    return absl::MakeConstSpan(inputs_);
  }
}
```

When calling `bar.GetInputs()` it seems like the only implementation found is the the one that returns a span of constant inputs. If I have an instance of bar, and want to create a span of non-const inputs, then I must cast bar to foo, and then call `GetInputs`.

If I cast bar to foo, then call `GetInputs`, I am then able to assign the result to a span of non-const inputs. Why does the compiler fail to identify the inherited non-const method with the correct return type? Is there a way to make the subclass identify that method?

In other words, is there a way to make the following code compile:

```
absl::Span<Input *const> tmp = bar.GetInputs()
```

Comment: `GetInputs` in the derived class is marked `const`; it **can't** call a non-const member function unless you cast away const.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I have a non-const instance of Bar, then that instance should be able to call either the const implementation, or the non-const inherited method.

Comment: A `const` member function promises not to modify any members of the object that it's being applied to. Calling a non-const member function would break that promise. If you need to call non-const member functions, don't mark your function `const`.

Comment: I'm not trying to call the const method, I'm trying to call the non-const method of the same name, inherited from Foo.  My goal is to be able to call the inherited non-const GetInputs method, inherited from Foo, via a non-const instance of Bar.

Comment: I've added one more line to the question to be more explicit about the behavior i'd like. But to reiterate, if I have a non-const instance of Bar, my goal is to get the inherited, non-const implemention of GetInput from Foo to be called, instead of the const implementation in Bar.

Comment: I tend to prefer a different name, like GetSettings() const and GetEditableSettings(). You want to be explicit if minor differences can result in changing the internal state of your object.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion: I thought you were asking how to force the derived-class version to call the non-const base class version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, it has nothing to do with virtual functions or "precedence" of const, but is plain old "name hiding".

```
#include <iostream>
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f(int)    { std::cout << "Base(int)\n"; }
    virtual void f(double) { std::cout << "Base(double)\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void f(double) { std::cout << "Derived(double)\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    int x=0;
    d.f(x);
}
```

output: Derived(double)

The issue is, name lookup doesn't work the way it seems you expect.
For a given scope, it searches for names to build an overload set.  Within the context of Derived, there is only one f(), so when it's found, the compiler *stops searching further for more overloads*.

It finds Derived(double) and that's the entire overload set, and so it is selected.  When you cast your derived class to a reference to the base, and then call something, both functions (declared in the base) are considered, and overload resolution selects the best match.

Now, normally, for polymorphic types you are working with the objects in terms of pointers/references to the base, so it's not an issue.  But if you are calling directly on the derived class (perhaps from inside a member of derived?) then it'll have this issue of the derived declaration hiding the base names.

To make the base names visible in the derived class, it's easy:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using base::f; // <<<<<<<< just add this
    virtual void f(double) { std::cout << "Derived(double)\n"; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Chris. I've got a followup question for you. If I rename the method in base to be f_mutable, then f_mutable is callable from Derived. Why does the compiler search Base to build the overload set in this case, but not search Base to build the overload set in the case where the names are the same?

Comment: It's a series of scopes that it searches.  First the current class, and if nothing is found, it goes up to parents, and so on.  One at a time it searches for names, and similarly in enclosing namespaces, until it runs out of higher scopes.  But normally, as soon as the name is found in one scope it stops searching outer scopes.  That's why inner scopes can "hide" names in outer scopes... they stop the search before the outer scopes are seen.  With no f_mutable in derived, it continues to the parent scope.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

Answer (score 1):

you should add

```
using foo::GetInputs;
```

in `bar`  class to expose the base class function.

you will be able to call the base class function if the object is non-const